# specifying proxy settings for apt-get in Ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apt-get

I' ve got Ubuntu running as guest on a Windows 7 OS in VMWare.

I've specified proxy settings and I can browse the internet in Firefox.

But when I try :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )

I've edited the file /etc/apt/apt.conf as explained in the doc:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@tmg:8080/";
```

but with no luck.

Any idea what I should do ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the proxy for apt seems correct. So as you said your host OS is M$ Windows. It is possible that you need to set the domain in your username and do something like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://domain\username:password@tmg:8080/";
```

Anyway i think the best way to share internet with guest OSes in VMware is NAT.